# belongs_to and has_many in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, class

I need some help. I have 2 classes:

**SharedInfo**

```
class SharedInfo < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :shared_info_type_id, :severity_id, :source_info_id, :created_date
  belongs_to :Severity, :foreign_key => :severity_id
  belongs_to :SharedInfoType, :foreign_key => :shared_info_type_id
  belongs_to :SourceInfo, :foreign_key => :source_info_id
end
```

**Severity**

```
class Severity < ActiveRecord::Base  
  has_many :SharedInfo, :foreign_key => :severity_id  
end
```

**The problem is:**
I have an instace `@sharedinfo` of class `SharedInfo`. When I call the following statement:

```
@sharedinfo.Severity
```

it return an error: "undefined". What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You have used `camelized` classes. You need to replace them with `underscore`.

```
belongs_to :severity, :foreign_key => :severity_id
belongs_to :shared_info_type, :foreign_key => :shared_info_type_id
belongs_to :source_info, :foreign_key => :source_info_id
```

HTH

Comment: It's still not work in my case. I don't know why, but It seem to be work only in ruby 1.8. I user ruby 1.9 rails 3.2

Comment: You would need to change other associations in Severity and other classes to underscore type. Please check and change those as well.